# Firestore multiple whereEqualTo on nested HashMap

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

considering that multiple whereArrayContains() not working, I have problems with multiple whereEqualTo() on nested HashMap.

I am making simple chat app with firebase and, in some point, I need to determine if chat document from firestore exists for two user ids. My current firestore setup for chat is:

```
chatId : {
    lastMessageText: string
    lastMessageTime: long
    memberIds: {
        userId1 : true
        userId2 : true
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
    chatsCollection
        .whereEqualTo("memberIds., + currentUser.getUsername() "true") // which is memberIds.userId1
        .whereEqualTo("memberIds." + opponentUser.getUsername(), "true")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                    // some logic
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        });
```

but always returns empty result. I checked could firestore and everything is there. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it's maybe trying to compare a boolean in the database with a String.  If you have a boolean type field in the database, you should also be using a boolean type value in the query (not a string with quotes around it).  Always make sure types match.

Comment: Shame on me. Correct. Thank you!